# What kind of licensing would you need for a Windows VM?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, licensing

Here is the scenario; I plan to have at least four Windows-based virtual machines running on a Linux host using VirtualBox on my network. My users will connect to their assigned virtual machine (multiple users per virtual machine) via RDP, from any device that supports an RDP client.

I've read some material on Windows virtual machine licensing, but it all seems so confusing, and all I want is a simple and straightforward answer. So, I have some questions...

1. How much do I have to pay (at once and/or over time) to operate the Windows virtual machines?
2. Are there any extra costs with there being multiple users logging into the same virtual machine via RDP?
3. I read somewhere that the machine used to access the Windows virtual machine needs a license, is this true? What if I use a Linux RDP client?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. License terms can vary from one locale to another. You need to contact your local reseller with these questions.

Comment: Every installation of Windows must be licensed in order to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The licensing for Windows desktop OS is per user or per CPU, that means that you need to have either type of desktop OS ([OEM, Retial, Volume](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49586-determine-if-windows-license-type-oem-retail-volume.html)). You can read about differences of per user and per machine licensing [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/windows10.aspx).

Desktop OS do not support Remote desktop Services licensing (RDS), i.e. you can't extend under of RDP connections for desktop PC. It is 2 simultaneous connections.

If you install Windows Server you can install 1 per-CPU license and buy additional CALs (Client Access Licenses) for Technical access depending on the number of RDP sessions you have.

You can read more about RDS CAL model [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license).

You can manage RDS licenses [here](https://activate.microsoft.com/).